# How can I add letters based on my link address? in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components, horizontal-scrolling

[image]

If I click on the link, I hope the "#" symbol will be added next to the text. (For Example "FUN" <-- If click this link, After that text change this -->"# FUN")  How do I implement it? Help me my geniuses
This is my jsx code

```
// styled-components
const ShapScroll = styled.div``;
const ShapTexts = styled.div`
  font-size: 20px;
  width: fit-content;
`;
const ShapText = styled.span`
  margin-right: 14px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid
    ${(props) => (props.current ? "#191919" : "transparent")};
  transition: border-bottom 0.3s ease-in-out;
`;

// react return
     <ShapTexts>
            <ShapScroll>
              <ShapText
                current={pathname === "/covid19"}
              >
                <ShapLinks to="/covid19">코로나19</ShapLinks>
              </ShapText>
              <ShapText current={pathname === "/news"}>
                <ShapLinks to="/news">뉴스</ShapLinks>
              </ShapText>
              .
              .
              .
              <ShapText
                current={pathname === "/sports"}}
              >
                <ShapLinks to="/sports">스포츠</ShapLinks>
              </ShapText>
            </ShapScroll>
          </ShapTexts>
```

Comment: For me, it's still not clear what you want to acheive.

Comment: @k-wasilewski I changed my writing clearly.

Comment: Can you add `ShapLinks` component

Comment: @SwarajGandhi https://github.com/eunjin0212/React-KakaoClone/blob/master/src/Screens/Shap/ShapHeader.jsx This link is my entire code at  Github. Look at the code and tell me how to add a "#" Genius.

Comment: I have tried your logic, it is working for me
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dust-ulq0b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SwarajGandhi OMG you're a genius THANK YOU :-)

Comment: My pleasure, an upvote will be good :P